# (.htaccess) allow one IP to httpdocs folder & redirect others to httpdocs\folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to allow only my IP to my website (\httpdocs) and redirect all other requests to another folder (\httpdocs\folder). How and can this be achieved through .htaccess?
 Currently I have redirect my domain to this folder, where the 'under construction ' page is, through plesk.

Comment: Please post your current .htaccess file and what you have tried so far

Comment: Options -Indexes                                                                                                       AuthType Basic                                                                                                              AuthName "Access to the Hidden Files"                                                                           AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd                                                                                    Require valid-user

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your root .htaccess file. `123.123.123.123` is the IP address to allow. I assume `/httpdocs` is the document root on your filesystem and is not a public URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOATE_ADDR} !=123.123.123.123
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder [NC]
RewriteRule .* /folder [R=302,L]
```

However, you should redirect to the actual "under construction" page, rather than just the "folder" that contains it.

Also, if this is "temporary maintenance" then consider implementing a 503 Service Unavailable instead:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55635/how-to-set-restrictions-on-my-website/55659#55659

Comment: Thanks for your response. In which folder (main or sub-domain) should I put my production and my under construction page, in your experience? I don't know exactly how easily I can move my production site when will be ready.

Comment: Personally, I would have the "under construction" page as a single page in the document root - since you don't want to share any resources (this is particularly true of a "down for maintenance" page). There shouldn't be any need to move the production site - that's the purpose of creating such a "redirect". I would not use a subdomain - since you will be redirecting users away from where the site will eventually be.

Comment: Actually the under construction page isn't a single html, it's PHP connected with DB. So I believe I have 2 options:a) allow my ip to /Folderx and redirect all the other requests to Foldera or b) adding a password protection Folderx , through htaccess.(as my current IP is dynamic) and redirect all others to Foldera.

Comment: If you are using additional resources for your "under construction" page then yes, keep all these in a separate folder. However, you are still redirecting to a single "under construction" page inside that folder initially. The basic principle is the same.

Comment: The IP address approach can be problematic if your IP address changes frequently or you need to allow access to other users (who might also have dynamic IPs). However, if you do use the "IP address" approach then you should not need to redirect yourself, only redirect "others" to Foldera. You create an "exception", not an "if...else...".